# htaccess 301 redirection with RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am using;

```
RewriteRule ^link1/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/link2-/([^/]*)$ link.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3
```

Last week I've sent my sitemap to Google but I realized that I've used `link2*` instead of `link2-` so I need to redirect all directory `link2-` to `link2*` with 301.

```
http://www.domain.com/link1/link2-/var1/var2/var3
```

Should redirect with 301 to

```
http://www.domain.com/link1/link2*/var1/var2/var3
```

Now our site is both listed with link2- and link2* As we know google does not like duplicate pages.

When I do

```
RedirectMatch 301 /link1/link2-/var http://www.domain.com/link1/link2*/var
```

It redirects to

```
http://www.domain.com/link1/link2*?var1=link2&var1=var2&var3
```

which means redirect mixed with rewrite...

I know it is a bit complicated but I really need help..

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `RedirectMatch` in this case, since it's a different module (mod_alias) it'll get applied along side all your mod_rewrite rules and cause conflicts. Use mod_rewrite instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/link2-(.*)$ /$1/link2*$2 [L,R=301]
```

The `*` will just end up getting encoded by the browser though, and it'll look like: `%2A`

Comment: It's doing the same thing mixing with other rewrite;

Link should be;
http://www.domain.com/link1/link2*/var1/var2/2

But after this code it become;
http://www.domain.com/list2*/var1/var2/var3?var1=C-&var2=var3&var=2

Answer (score 0):

I've used Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); with php instead of htaccess hoping it wont be a problem with google.. Thx